# Is there a nice way to express the power set of a set $H$ minus the largest subset in the power set?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Given the definition of the power set of a set $H$, $\mathcal P(H)$, as the set of all subsets of $H$, what is $\mathcal P(H) \setminus H$? Ie the power set minus the largest subset, $H$ its self. Something like

$$\mathcal P(H) - \{ H \} = \sum\limits_{i\in H}\mathcal P(H\setminus i) - \sum\limits_{(i,j)\in H, i\neq j}\mathcal P(H\setminus i, j) + \dots$$

Where the sum just denotes adding two sets together in such a way that we keep any repeated elements.

Explanation of the summation: I care about repetitions of set elements, so cannot use the more elegant solution suggested below of using the set union

Comment: I think all you want and need is the left side of your equality. I can't make sens of the right side. Why do you need a special complicated way to say this?

Comment: I don't understand this. What are $i$ and $j$? Why is $H$ a subset of its power set? What are the sums?

Comment: $i, j$ are elements of $H$, and the powerset of $H$ by construction contains $H$ as a subset. Also, and apologies for the confusion here, I am using sums instead of set unions because I am counting repetitions of elements. To give some context, this problem is arising in a computer science setting, where I am trying to convert a sum over a power set of H to a sum over power sets of subsets of H, and as such my resulting expression must deal with repetitions of elements

Answer (score 1):

"Adding two sets together in such a way that we keep any repeated elements" is the same as taking the union of two sets. It would be correct to say
$$\mathcal{P}(H)-\{H\} = \bigcup_{i \in H} \mathcal{P}(H -\{ i\}).$$
Why? Well if $A \in \mathcal{P}(H)-\{H\}$, then $A$ is a subset of $H$ but it is not all of $H$. So there exists $i \in H$ such that $i \notin A$... Conversely, if $A \in \bigcup_{i \in H} \mathcal{P}(H-\{i\})$ then there exists $i\in H$ such that $A \in \mathcal{P}(H -\{ i\})$. Hence $A \subseteq H- \{i\} \subseteq H$, but $i \notin A$...

I'm not sure why you are subtracting sets, but that is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of using $\Sigma$, write $\bigcup_{i \in H}$, as (if I understood you correctly) you are thinking about the union of subsets of $P(H)$.

$\bigcup_{i \in H} P(H \backslash i)$ then consists of all subsets of $H$ that do not contain all elements of $H$, i.e. $\bigcup_{i \in H} P(H \backslash i) = P(H) - \{H\}$.

If you additionally subtract the set you did in your post, you will instead get the set of subsets of $H$ which are missing exactly one element, but that is not what you wanted.

Comment: Apologies for brutalising the standard notiation. I need an expression that takes into account `over-counting', whereas the set union doesnt care about repetitions of elements. Thats why im using the (horrible) sum notation. Perhaps it would be better to think of these as lists rather than sets. For example, in your expression $\bigcup_{i \in H} P(H \backslash i)$  we end up with $|H|$ emptysets being generated, but the $\bigcup$ just treats them as one. So I am looking for an expression which returns $\mathcal P(H) - \{H\}$ from a sum of sets so that there is no overcounting

Comment: to give some context, this is for a computer science problem, converting a sum over a power set of H to a sum over power sets of subsets of H. So overcounting will be a problem. Perhaps this shouldnt have been posted under `set theory'

Comment: @jdizzle: It sounds like you're confusing *sets* with *sizes of sets*. In a set, each element is counted only once, so if you take a union of many overlapping sets then you still only get one of each thing. If you want to compute the *size* of $\mathcal{P}(H) - \{ H \}$, then... well, that's just $2^{|H|}-1$. (I should add that the size of a union of sets is not just the sum of their sizes, unless they're pairwise disjoint.)

Comment: Yes, apologies this question is not about sets, but rather lists of objects and the lists formed by taking the powersets of those lists. I will find the proper thread to migrate it to